# Вывод текста в отдельное окно

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть цикл и периодически по заданному условию у меня печатается текст простым print.  Работаю в PyCharm, если это важно. Необходимо вывести текст в отдельное маленькое окно наподобие, как на скрине.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обычное маленькое окно поверх моего (браузера), главное чтобы текст в нем обновлялся, код будет работать все время.

Для этого нужен дополнительный модуль, вроде tkinter? В Python есть вывод в текстовый файл, но он должен быть закрыт для этого? Изменения же не могут происходить в открытом текстовом файле по команде из Python?

Я пробую простейший код с tkinter. Как мне сделать окно "самообновляемым"? Я вставлю свою функцию в цикл и хочу чтобы время в моем окне менялось- т.е было актуальным, каждую секунду. Чтобы окно не приходилось, конечно, закрывать-открывать.

```
mytext = str(time.time())
root = Tk()
text = Text()
text.pack()
text.insert(1.0, mytext)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать окно на Tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

label = None

def window():
    global label

    root = Tk()
    label = Label(root, text = '', fg='black')
    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

А в начале твоего кода надо добавить:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target = window)
thread.start()
time.sleep(1)
```

Чтобы изменить текст:

```
label.config(text = 'text')
```

Можно попробовать так:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

label = None

def window():
    global label

    root = Tk()
    label = Label(root, text = '', fg='black')
    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()

thread = threading.Thread(target = window)
thread.start()
time.sleep(1)

while True:
    mytext = str(time.time())
    label.config(text = mytext)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я добавил еще вопрос

Comment: Окно необходимо создавать в отдельном потоке и потом уже передавать в него текст

Answer (score 1):

Ипортируем модуль для многопоточности:

```
import threading
```

Добавляем эти две строчки где у тебя создается окно, можешь их добавить перед main loop:

```
threading_start = threading.Theard( target = #имя вашей функции , которое создает второе окно без скобок )
threading_start.start()
```

Comment: Спасибо, я добавил еще вопрос